# UTF-8 3 and 4 bytes character representation

Tags: c, utf-8

I have this *C* code to print the character of 2 bytes in UTF-8 encoding scheme:

```
printf("%c%c", 0xC0 + cp / 0x40, 0x80 + cp % 0x40);
```

How I can represent 3 and 4 bytes in the same way of UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've called `setlocale` and the locale is using UTF-8 and `wchar_t` stores Unicode codepoint values, you can just do:

```
printf("%lc", (wint_t)cp);
```

Otherwise, for 3-byte representations, you could do:

```
printf("%c%c%c", 0xE0 + cp/0x40/0x40, 0x80 + cp/0x40%0x40, 0x80 + cp%0x40);
```

And similarly for 4-byte. Note that this approach is **not** recommended since you could easily accidentally output an invalid 3-byte representation for a character whose UTF-8 representation is actually 2-byte.

Comment: Nicely said.  @OP _why_ do you want to print this way?

Comment: There being a UTF-8 locale is platform-dependent. It will not work in VC++.

Comment: @CoryNelson: Indeed. If that's a problem, writing a function to convert a Unicode codepoint to a sequence of bytes in UTF-8 would be useful. Here's just about the simplest fully-correct way to do it: http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/multibyte/wcrtomb.c